# get the previous last date of the month in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below query which is taking the last date of the month when this query is running on the current month. But as i am going to use this query in stored procedure and this procedure will run may be on the 1st or 2nd or 3rd of the current month then in this case i want to take the previous last month date everytime. For example if the query runs on 2nd or 3rd february then it will return the date with 31st January which is previous month last date.

The `C_DATE` column is date datatype

```
Select * from C_LOG
WHERE C_DATE = LAST_DAY(to_date(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))-1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE )` to get the current day of the month. If this is below your threshold then you can get the last day of the previous month otherwise use the last day of the current month:

```
SELECT *
FROM   C_LOG
WHERE  C_DATE = CASE
                WHEN EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE ) <= 3
                THEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
                ELSE LAST_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) )
                END
```

*Note*:

Do not use `to_date(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')` since `TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` takes a string as its first argument so Oracle will implicitly cast the date to a string; effectively doing:

```
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    SYSDATE,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  'YYYYMMDD'
)
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not `YYYYMMDD` then the query will fail. Since this is a session parameter, each user can change it at any time and your query will fail for any user who changes that parameter without ever changing sql of the query.

Instead, if you want to remove the time component of a `DATE` data type, use the `TRUNC` function.

Comment: so for example if the month in the feb where day is less than 3 for example 3rd Feb then this query will take the last date of the previous month i.e 31st Jan. If the month is Jan itself then it will take the last month of the date i.e 31st Jan right ?

Comment: @Andrew If the day of the month is the 1st, 2nd or 3rd then it will use the last day of the previous month otherwise it will use the last day of the current month.

Comment: thanks but i am worried about NLS setting as you mentioned that it should be YYYYMMDD. Because i will deploy my procedure in Production then i dont know whether there it has this NLS setting YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Andrew Then do not rely on implicit casts between dates and strings - my answer shows how to remove the time component using `TRUNC` and that does not rely on casting the date to a string so will not encounter any issues with users changing the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ADD_MONTHS function,

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE), -1) FROM DUAL;
```

you can also use the TRUNC function

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')-1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another variation:

```
SELECT *
  FROM c_log
 WHERE c_date =
          TRUNC (
             LAST_DAY (
                CASE
                   WHEN EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSDATE) <= 3
                   THEN
                      ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1)
                   ELSE
                      SYSDATE
                END));
```

Comment: what does this condition WHEN EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSDATE) <= 3 exactly do ?

Comment: It returns *day number*; today is Jan 18th, so it'll return "18". It is similar to a value returned by TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD'), if you're more used to it. Note that you'd have to apply TO_NUMBER to strings, otherwise you might get unexpected results (for example, '13' comes before '2' when sorted).

Comment: so for example if the month in the feb where day is less than 3 for example 3rd Feb then this query will take the last date of the previous month i.e 31st Jan. If the month is Jan itself then it will take the last month of the date i.e 31st Jan right ? and this query will not fail right if the nls setting is not in format i.e YYYYMMDD ?

Comment: For days 1, 2 and 3 it will return the last day of previous month. For example, if it was Jan 2nd, it would return Dec 31st. If it was Mar 1st, it would return Feb 28th (or Feb 29th, depending on leap year). It doesn't depend on NLS settings.